# Looping (iteration) over a pandas dataframe - how to choose desired values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a DataFrame containing informations about airports. Using for loop, I want to extract name of the airport and total seats from the most recent year reported. I am only interested in seeing values higher than 20000.

This code prints out all names and seats:

```
for name, seats in zip(sa_airports['Name'], sa_airports['TotalSeats']):
    print(name, ' : ', seats)
```

I tried this:

```
for name, seats in zip(sa_airports['Name'], sa_airports['TotalSeats']):
    if sa_airports['TotalSeats'] > 20000:
        print(name, ' : ', seats)
```

But error occured: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Because of that, i tried to put every option into the loop, yet nothing gives me result I want. Example:

```
for name, seats in zip(sa_airports['Name'], sa_airports['TotalSeats']):
    if (sa_airports['TotalSeats'] > 20000).any():
        print(name, ' : ', seats)
```

This code checks if any value in totalseats is > 20000 and it is true, so it prints out everything

Answer (score 2):

In general you should (almost) never use loops with Pandas.  Use vectorized operations instead.  They are more performant and easier to understand.

```
filtered = sa_airports.loc[sa_airports['TotalSeats'] > 20000][['Name', 'TotalSeats']]
for name, seats in filtered.itertuples(index=False):
    print(name, ' : ', seats)
```